# Plotly-Dash: How can I make a dataframe with crosstab that still shows the original column names?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["good", "good"], ["bad", "perfect"], ["perfect", "good"], ["perfect", "good"]]), columns=['after', 'before'])
a = np.unique(df.to_numpy())
df = pd.crosstab(df['before'], df['after']).reindex(columns=a, index=a, fill_value=0)
print (df)
after    bad  good  perfect
before                     
bad        0     0        0
good       0     2        1
perfect    1     1        0
```

When i print the `df` like this the headers "before" and "after" appear. However, when I don't print but only view the `df` these dissapear. [image]

I would like to convert this dataframe to a dash DataTable displayed in the same way as I print the `df`. So far, all DataTables I have managed to create are in the same format as when I view the df instead of when I print it. I hope my question is clear.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the elements `after` and `before` are ignored seems to be that they are part of a multi-index and are actually the names for the index and the columns, retrievable by `df.index.name` and `df.columns.name`, respectively. If you run `df.reset_index()` you'll get this:

```
after   before  bad good    perfect
0       bad     0   0       0
1       good    0   1       2
2       perfect 1   0
```

And that's close to what you want, but not quite. One way you can retain your desired information and make your table look good is to retrieve `df.index.name` and `df.columns.name` before resetting the index, and then rename the first column to `before / after` using `df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: iname + ' / ' + cname}, inplace=True)`.

Here's the result:

[image]

#### Complete code for JupyterDash:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


# data
#df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["good", "good"], ["bad", "perfect"], ["perfect", "good"], ["perfect", "good"]]), columns=['after', 'before'])
a = np.unique(df.to_numpy())
df = pd.crosstab(df['before'], df['after']).reindex(columns=a, index=a, fill_value=0)#.reset_index()

#df = df.reset_index(level=['after', 'before'])
iname = df.index.name
cname = df.columns.name
df = df.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: iname + ' / ' + cname}, inplace=True)

app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

app.run_server(mode='inline', port = 8077, dev_tools_ui=True,
          dev_tools_hot_reload =True, threaded=True)
```

If JupyterDash is not your cup of tea, just follow the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63962975/plotly-how-to-rewrite-a-standard-dash-app-to-launch-it-in-jupyterlab/63962980#63962980) to turn it into a standard dash app