# Get boxplot rectangles coordinates in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, boxplot

I need to draw additional graphics on top of plotly `go.Box` traces, therefore I need to know X and Y coordinates for boxplot rectangle vertices. So far the only solution I came up with is basically recalculating everything (quartiles; X positions based on `boxgap`, `boxgroupgap`, etc.), then manually setting the y-axis range to know where everything will end up on the plot. This seems very cumbersome.

Is there a way in python to get the coordinates of `go.Box` boxplot elements, especially the grouped boxplots with categorical x-axis? As far as I understand these coordinates are calculated in JS frontend -- maybe there is some trick to get them back with Dash using callbacks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly-Dash: How to code interactive callbacks for hover functions in plotly dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64817038/plotly-dash-how-to-code-interactive-callbacks-for-hover-functions-in-plotly-das)